# Determining orthogonal polynomials based on Lanczo’s Orthogonalization theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I am supposed to determine the first three orthogonal polynomails, i.e., $ \Phi_{1},\Phi_{2}, \Phi_{3} $ for some integral $\langle f,x \rangle = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x) dx $.

This is what I have so far. According to Lanczo's Theorem,

> $ \Phi_{1} = 1$
>
> $ \Phi_{2} = x - \alpha_{2}$
>
> $ \Phi_{3} = x*\Phi_{2} - \alpha_{3}*\Phi_{2} -\beta_{3}*\Phi_{0} $

where

> $ \alpha_{k} =   \frac{\langle  x*\Phi_{k-1} ,\Phi_{k-1} \rangle}{\gamma_{k-1}} \enspace k = 1,2...  $
>
> $ \gamma_{k} =   \langle \Phi_{k}, \Phi_{k} \rangle = \langle x^{k},\Phi_{k} \rangle \enspace k = 0,1...  $
>
> $ \beta_{k} =    \langle  \frac{x*\Phi_{k-1},\Phi_{k-2}}{\gamma_{k-2}} \rangle \enspace k = 2,3...       $

and this is as far as I have gotten:

> $ \Phi_{1} = 1$
>
> $ \gamma_{0} = \langle \Phi_{0}, \Phi_{0} \rangle = \langle 1,1 \rangle   $
>
> $\alpha_{1} =   \frac{\langle  x*\Phi_{0} ,\Phi_{0} \rangle}{\gamma_{0}} = \frac{x*\langle 1,1 \rangle}{\langle 1,1 \rangle} = x  $
>
> $ \Phi_{2} = x-x = 0$

But I do not believe that $ \Phi_{2}$ should equal zero since it should have two roots over this interval. I'm looking for some guidance in where I went wrong, and where I should move from here.

EDIT:

Brainfart. Just remembered the notation $ \langle f,g \rangle$ refers to $ \int f(x)g(x) dx $, where the limits of integration are predetermined by the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're doing the homework for Corwin's Numerical Analysis class?

I'm confused on that because I never took real analysis, and my linear algebra book doesn't have an explanation for this. The rest of the internet has run my search dry, too.

My question is, what does "r" stand for?

I tried matching the interval [a,b] = [-1,1] in the lecture notes to figure out what r is, but I still have no idea.